# After token verification reset form doesn't process

Tags: php

A user forgets password on my site.
They enter username and an email is fired off containing a link with a token appended to the url of the reset page.
When the link is clicked, token is verified for existence and expiry.
If good, reset password form is shown else error message and Try Again.
All is good to here.
When the user enters a new password and hits Submit, the appended part of the url disappears and just the regular page url is in the address bar.
The reset password form is just sitting there blank.
Since I use $_GET to retrieve the token and $_POST to process the form, could this be my problem?
I include the page code here:

```
<?php
require_once ('functions.inc.php');
include("header.php");
require_once ('config.inc.php');
?>
<body> 
<div data-role="page" id="resetpassword">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Reset Password</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
<?php
$page_title = 'ResetPassword';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') { 
$tk = ($_GET['token']);
$q1 = "SELECT uname, request_time FROM users WHERE token = '$tk'";
    $r1 = mysqli_query($dbconn,$q1)or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($dbconn));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r1); 
    $user = $row['uname'];
    $then = $row['request_time'];
    //echo $then;
    $now = time();
    //echo $now;
    $expired = ($now - $then);
    //echo $expired;
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($r1);       
    if ($num_rows !== 1 || $expired > 900){
    echo "An error has prevented a password change.<br />Most likely the link has       expired.<br />Please try again.";   
    ?>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar">
    <a href="../index.php" data-role="button">Try Again</a> 
    </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div>
    <?php
    exit();
}           
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {         
        $trimmed = array_map('trim', $_POST);
        if (preg_match ('/^[[:alnum:]]{8,20}$/', ($trimmed['password']))) {
            $p = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn, ($trimmed['password']));
            // hash the password
            require ("passhash.php");
            $pass_hash = PassHash::hash($p);
            } else {
            echo '<p>Please enter a valid password!</p>';
            }
            if ($pass_hash) {
            $q2 = "UPDATE `users` SET upass='$pass_hash' WHERE uname='$user'";
            $r2 = mysqli_query($dbconn, $q2)or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($dbconn));
            if ($r2 == TRUE) {
            echo "<p>Password Changed!</p>";
            }
            }               
?>
</div><!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar">
<a href="../index.php" data-role="button">Login</a> 
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
<?php
}
}
?>
<form id="passwordreset" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?token=<?php echo $tk;?>" data-ajax="false"> 
<p>Choose a new password.<br />
Letters and numbers only.<br />
Minimum of 8 Maximum of 20 characters.</p>
<label for="password" class="ui-hidden-accessible">New Password:</label> 
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="New Password"/>
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>Submit</button>  
</form>
</div><!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar">
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using both POST and GET doesn't cause any problems as it states here:
[Want to use both GET and POST methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036858/want-to-use-both-get-and-post-methods)

But when the form posts the data, the POST url also needs to include the GET params (the token). So modify the post url to send the whole data you need.

Comment: Sorry I took so long to get back. Thank you for the response and the link. my form now has action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?token='$tk'" but still does not process the form.

Comment: Well I am not sure. When I enter the new password and click Submit the form simply appears again but it is blank. I check the database which I am trying to update and nothing there has changed. The first part of my script works fine. I let the token expire and it shows me the error. If I try to use a non existant token, I get the error. Just like it is supposed to. It is the update with new password part which just does not work.

Comment: I get nothing when trying to get number of rows no error nothing.

Comment: Just tried SELECT * instead of UPDATE with same result. It seems like the script is just ignoring the database. However the top part does connect to the db and returns proper results.

Comment: Hang on a minute. I just started over and signed up as new user but couldn't login after registering. Maybe my problem is the hashing of the password. Off to investigate.

Comment: Okay that wasn't it. Something different but I fixed that. New user registered and logged in no problem. The problem is still when the user forgets password. Email gets sent, link gets clicked, token verified, new password form shows,submit clicked, password form shows again! Just a little bit frustrating.

Comment: Anybody have any other suggestions?