# w3schools did not explain this in PHP can someone explain it to me?

Tags: php, html

Hey guys I am learning PHP now and actually w3schools does not have listed what is the purpose if these things. Sorry I am not familiar with the names and conecepts as well, so was hoping someone can kind go over it with me. I searched youtube videos, but they usually do not call it by the correct name. They just say "place "post in here because it needs to call what you have in HTML" but what is $_POST? a variable? ect

```
        <form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
            <!-- The $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] is a super global variable that returns the filename of the currently executing script.'
            So, the $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] sends the submitted form data to the page itself,
            instead of jumping to a different page. This way, the user will get error messages on the same page as the form.-->
            Name: <input type="text" name="name"> <br>
            E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"> <br>
            Website: <input type="text" name="website"> <br>

            <input type="submit" value="send!"> 
        </form>
        <?php
//        $name = $email = $website = "";

        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            echo ($_POST["name"]);
            echo ($_POST["email"]);
            echo ($_POST['website']);
        }

//        function test_input($data) {
//            $data = trim($data);
//            $data = stripslashes($data);
//            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
//        }
        ?>
```

wondering in the bottom what is trim, stripslashes, and why is it calling or whatever its doing "htmlspecialchars" again if its located in the action""> line?

Comment: Obligatory link: http://w3fools.com

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: You probably wouldn't have so many questions if you didn't try to learn from such a poor source. Search around or get a book or two but try to stay away from w3schools.

Comment: Guys, don't downvote just because he chose a poor source of learning, that isn't his fault. How was he to know w3schools sucks ..

Comment: As others are pointing out, w3schools is not a good source of reliable information. That said, some of the comments (and down votes) here are too harsh. OP asked a reasonable question, and clearly already made an effort to find and understand the answer. What seems obvious to many users on here may not be obvious to a new programmer.

Comment: @EdCottrell I second that.

Comment: I use w3schools regularly for help with html and css syntax. Not sure why all the hate on it.

Answer (score 5):

`$_POST` is a reserved "superglobal" variable, meaning it is:

1. Created automatically by the server and
2. Available everywhere.

It automatically contains all data sent to the server with an HTTP POST request.  Technically, it is ([**from the manual**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)):

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method.

So if you have a form with `name` and `email` input fields, `$_POST` is an array with keys named `name` and `email`, which contain the data submitted by the user.  You could access these with `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['email']`, respectively.

There are several other superglobal variables, namely:

- `$GLOBALS`
- `$_SERVER`
- `$_GET`
- `$_POST`
- `$_FILES`
- `$_COOKIE`
- `$_SESSION`
- `$_REQUEST`
- `$_ENV`

You can learn much more about this by reading [**the manual entry on `$_POST`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) or [**the manual entry on superglobal variables**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php).

To answer your other questions:

[**`trim()`**](http://www.php.net/trim) removes white space (like spaces, tabs, and new lines) from the beginning and end of a string. For example, `trim('    foo     ')` produces just `foo` without the spaces. You can also make it remove other characters. Say you have `xxxfooxxx`.  `trim('xxxfooxxx', 'x')` will take away the `x`s and leave you just `foo`.

[**`stripslashes()`**](https://www.php.net/stripslashes) removes slashes from a string that has escaped characters.  For example (from the manual):

```
$str = "Is your name O\'reilly?";

// Outputs: Is your name O'reilly?
echo stripslashes($str);
```

[**`htmlspecialchars()`**](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars) turns special characters into HTML "entities." Specifically, it changes the following:

- `&` (ampersand) becomes `&amp;`
- `"` (double quote) becomes `&quot;` when `ENT_NOQUOTES` is not set.
- `'` (single quote) becomes `&#039;` (or `&apos;`) only when `ENT_QUOTES` is set.
- `<` (less than) becomes `&lt;`
- `>` (greater than) becomes `&gt;`

Answer (score 3):

#### `$_POST` is part of the  ["superglobal"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) family.

---

I quote from the manual:

> Superglobals are built-in variables that are always available in all
>   scopes.
>
> Several predefined variables in PHP are "superglobals", which means
>   they are available in all scopes throughout a script. There is no need
>   to do `global $variable`; to access them within functions or methods.
>
> These superglobal variables are:
>
> - `$GLOBALS`
> - `$_SERVER`
> - `$_GET`
> - `$_POST`
> - `$_FILES`
> - `$_COOKIE`
> - `$_SESSION`
> - `$_REQUEST`
> - `$_ENV`

Then in your PHP handler, the form's element would be accessed in this fashion:

**A basic example:**

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name']; // taken from <input type="text" name="name">
echo $name;             // would echo the entered name from the form.
```

**Something important to remember:**

When using superglobals, they **must** be in uppercase letters.

`$_post` and `$_Post` for example are considered **invalid**. Use `$_POST` < **exactly** like this etc.

Some have/do that mistake, and will not work if not using the proper syntax (uppercase).

**Also**, the underscore `_` between the `$` and the superglobal name `POST` for example, is also required. `$POST` < being **invalid**. Again, use `$_POST` - `$_GET` - `$_REQUEST` etc.

---

> #### About certain functions and predefined variables

1. [`trim()`](http://www.php.net/trim)

   - Strips whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string
2. [`stripslashes()`](http://www.php.net/stripslashes)

   - Un-quotes a quoted string
3. [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)

   - Converts special characters to HTML entities
4. [`$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

   - Executes from the same location of the originating script. Using `action=""` does the same job.
5. [`$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

   - Which request method was used to access the page; i.e. 'GET', 'HEAD', 'POST', 'PUT'

---

> #### Eventual/potential database work

Should you later want to adventure yourself in [**databases**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL), you could use these variables as shown below, using [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/mysqli) as an example:

```
<?php
// DB connection credentials
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['name']);
// rest of DB query
//
```

`$con` being something to the effect of:

```
$con = new mysqli("host","username", "password", "database");
```

Answer (score 2):

`$_POST[]` is one of PHPs [**Superglobals**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php).

From the PHP Manual:

> Superglobals are built-in variables that are always available in all scopes

These are:

- $_SERVER - *Contains information about the Server & Execution Enviroment*
- $_GET - *Contains HTTP GET variables*
- $_POST - *Contains HTTP POST variables*
- $_FILES - *Contains HTTP File Upload variables*
- $_COOKIE - *Contains HTTP Cookies*
- $_SESSION - *Contains Session variables*
- $_REQUEST - *Contains HTTP Request variables*
- $_ENV - *Contains Environment variables*

They contain information about the enviroment that PHP is running in as well as information passed to the script etc.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said `$_POST` is a [super global variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php).

With regards to your other questions, you are better off going onto [php.net](http://www.php.net/) and searching for the function name specifically.

- [`trim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)
- [`stripslashes()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)
- [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Answer (score 1):

So, `$_POST` has been covered enough by the other answers.

`trim`, `stripslashes` and `htmlspecialchars` are used to format strings and those 3 are rather basic, you'll probably use them often.

`trim` cuts off leading and trailing whitespaces, so that your resulting string starts and ends with an actual visible character. This is usually used to clean up user-submitted data and remove parts that don't really hold any information. It can also be used for some tricky formatting in combination with concatenation (`.`) though.

`stripslashes` reverses the `addslashes` function. The latter is important to sanitize user-entered data and take a big step towards avoiding injection-type attacks, where a user enters executable code in a way that makes your server actually execute it. Usually though, you don't want to output data in this "safe" form because it looks strange, so you'll call `stripslashes` just before creating your output in order to revert the string to its original form.

`htmlspecialchars` is necessary for creating html output that contains some characters used or reserved by `html`, such as `<` and `&`. Since `PHP` usually creates `html` code, those characters are transmitted in a way that makes `html` understand them as if you wrote a source file with them. But sometimes, you want to just display the character ("Romeo & Juliet"). In those cases, you need `htmlspecialchars` to transform your string into a 'clean' string that will show on the user's screen exactly the way it shows in your script (minus the quotation marks).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my newbie explanation:

$_POST is an array of all the POST data sent by the client to the server

To see it, use this:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

You can also see the GET data with

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

And finally everything (including cookies):

```
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

[Want to use both GET and POST methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036858/want-to-use-both-get-and-post-methods)

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a form:

```
 <form method="POST">
    <label>Username: <input type="text" name="username" ></label><br>
    <label>Password: <input type="password" name="password" ></label><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

There's two important things going on here:

- each input (of the text-input type, not the submit button at the bottom) has a **name**
- the form has an attribute 'method' that says **"POST"**

If you submit this form, the browser will send the data as an associative array to the webserver using the POST-method. This array will then be passed to this PHP variable: `$_POST` (which is one of the super global variables, look that up if you want to know more).
In PHP you can then use what was entered as follows:

```
echo "The username you entered is: ".$_POST["username"];
```

You can do the same with $_POST["password"], obviously.
Now there's also the GET-method. The form would look like this:

```
<form method="GET">
    <label>Username: <input type="text" name="username" ></label><br>
    <label>Password: <input type="password" name="password" ></label><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The only thing that changed was the 'method' attribute of the form. Now, when you submit this, there will be two differences with using the POST-method:

- The data you send will be visible in the url in the following form: website.com**?username=jack&password=ilikepotatoes** (the **?** indicates the start of the data)
- The data will be given to PHP in same form, but under a different name: **$_GET** in stead of $_POST

So in PHP, you can access this data this way:

```
echo "The username you entered is: ".$_GET["username"];
```

Which one you use, is up to you, but for things like logon-forms it's better to use the POST-method as this doesn't show the data in the url like the GET-method does.